# Issue on Getting Custom Attribute Data From Checkbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/kkLLx0sj/1/) and let me know why I am not able to get Custom Attribute data Values on each checkbox check?

```js
$('.styles-control').change(function () {
         console.log(this.data('style'));

});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="road">Roads
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="poi">Poi
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="water">Water
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="transit">translink
<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dataset.style:

```
 $('.styles-control').change(function () {
     console.log(this.dataset.style);
 });
```

```js
     $('.styles-control').change(function () {
         console.log(this.dataset.style);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="road">Roads
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="poi">Poi
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="water">Water
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="transit">translink
<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

`.data` is a jQuery method, wrap `this` in jQuery

```
console.log($(this).data('style')); //this.getAttribute("data-style")
```